# why if statement does not compare the data in text file? python

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I am trying to create a simple login system. The problem is, if statement is not executed at all even when I enter the correct username and password. this is my first time asking question.
data from text file:

```
ted, teddy@gmail.com, 12345678
bean, bean@gmail.com, 12345678
```

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    f_read = f.read().split()
    print(f_read)



n = str(input("Do you have an account?yes/no: "))

while n == "yes":
    username_check = input("enter a username: ")
    checkpass = input("enter your password: ")

    for line in open('data.txt','r').readlines():
        loginDetails = line.split()
        if username_check == loginDetails[0] and checkpass ==  loginDetails[2]:
           print("accepted")
           break
    else:
        print('not accepted')
```

this is the output.

```
Do you have an account?yes/no: yes
enter a username: bean
enter your password: 12345678
not accepted
enter a username:
```

Comment: Check the value of loginDetails. Also post the data.txt file for more clarity.

Comment: bean, will match the result. You have to remove that trailing comma at the end of the usernames, the answers given below will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you split this line:

```
ted, teddy@gmail.com, 12345678
```

using `str.split()` you get a list of `['ted,' , 'teddy@gmail.com,' , '12345678\n']`.

You need to split at `,` and strip whitespaces:

```
loginDetails = [part.strip() for part in line.split(',')]
```

Comment: it works. but why the code is asking enter username and password again?

Comment: @tedy Because the `break` breaks from the _for_ loop - not the while loop. Set `n` to something different to "yes" or add a second guard for your if condition that lets it terminate if a valid login was given.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the comma that separates the fields in the file.

When you do `loginDetails = line.split()` the contents of `loginDetails` will be e.g. `['bean,', 'bean@gmail.com,', '12345678']`.

When you compare `'bean'` to `'bean,'` they will not match.

Possible solution include to either change the format of your input file, or use [the comma-separated values module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to read the file. Or split on the comma, as shown in another answer.